# Subpages aren't working in Kirby even with htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mamp, kirby

I'm trying to setup Kirby locally using MAMP. My MAMP setup I have it so I can point run multiple sites as virtual hosts. I use this code:

```
NameVirtualHost * 

<VirtualHost *> 
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs" 
ServerName localhost 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *> 
DocumentRoot "/Users/oscargodson/Dropbox/projects/icarus" 
ServerName dev.icarus
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to dev.icarus the initial page loads totally fine. All the CSS, images, everything. Once I try to go to a subpage, including the panel, I get the 404. I know for sure the htaccess file is in the folder. I tried using the git install and the manual zip install. I also made sure in in my `httpd.conf` file I have rewrite turned on

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I'm not sure what else to look up. Googling just kept returning results for htaccess file being missing.

***EDIT***

Here's the htaccess file per request. It is the default one that works if I keep my project inside of the htdocs directory in MAMP. I tried uncommenting the RewriteBase and making it just `/` (a total guess) but that didn't help at all.

```
# Kirby .htaccess

# rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# enable awesome urls. i.e.:
# http://yourdomain.com/about-us/team
RewriteEngine on

# make sure to set the RewriteBase correctly
# if you are running the site in a subfolder.
# Otherwise links or the entire site will break.
#
# If your homepage is http://yourdomain.com/mysite
# Set the RewriteBase to:
#
# RewriteBase /

# block text files in the content folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ index.php [L]

# block all files in the site folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) index.php [L]

# block all files in the kirby folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^kirby/(.*) index.php [L]

# make panel links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^panel/(.*) panel/index.php [L]

# make site links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# Additional recommended values
# Remove comments for those you want to use.
#
# AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
#
# php_flag short_open_tag on
```

Comment: Can we see the content of the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MikeRockett updated with the htaccess file in Kirby

Comment: My apologies - should have mentioned this earlier. You need to set `AllowOverride All` in your virtual host configuration (by the addition of a `Directory` section in each one). Let me know if you need help doing this.

Comment: That did it! Thank you @MikeRockett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike Rockett in the comments pointed me in the right direction. In the `httpd.conf` file I had to change

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Then I restarted MAMP and it worked!